# Как отцентрировать текст внутри блока с возможностью переполнения

Tags: html, css, выравнивание

Есть блок, внутри которого находится текст. Текст сам переносится браузером по строкам.
Надо отцентрировать текст по вертикали.

Для этого могло бы подойти центрирование при помощи

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

Если бы не один момент. Надо, чтобы если текст не вмещается в блок, он обрезался. А `table-cell` расширяется, чтобы вместить всё содержимое.

Как сделать вертикальное центрирование текста таким образом, чтобы у контейнера работало `overflow:hidden`?

```css
div {
    width: 30em;
    height: 11em;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

PS: `contenteditable` добавлено просто так, чтобы можно было прямо в сниппете посмотреть, что происходит при изменении количества текста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С вложенными дивами это должно выглядеть так. Не думаю, что можно одним обойтись.

```css
div.outer {
  width: 30em;
  height: 11em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.inner {
  max-height: 11em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" contenteditable>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что-то я не подумал про `max-height` - всё пытался просто `height` присобачить. Спасибо!!!